# Level of detail tuning (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a possibility to change the way names(labels)/boundaries shown on the map on different zoom levels?

For example I have 17 zoom levels. I'd like to start showing details (country names) only on zoom level 10.

In other words: how the level of detail on the map connected with zoom level and how it can be  tuned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function show_map(lat, lng) {
    var labelsOff = [{
        featureType: "administrative",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }];

    var labelsOn = [{
        featureType: "administrative",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "on"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "on"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "on"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "on"
        }]
    }];

    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.477391, -0.000853);
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    map.setOptions({
        styles: labelsOff
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() >= 10) {
                map.setOptions({
                    styles: labelsOn
                });
            } else {
                map.setOptions({
                    styles: labelsOff
                });
            }
        });
    });

}


show_map();
```

Hope that's what you were looking for. Obviously you can edit those feature types for hiding different things.

Sorry, had to edit. Forgot [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEMun/)!